# Child object calling a parent's function through a global variable

Tags: javascript, event-programming

I have a `Session` object, of which a single global instance `session` holds the current session, which can persist itself to the server, handle undos redos etc.

The session holds an instance of `Objects` which is in this example basically a set of `Cars` objects. When user changes e.g. a marker on a map representing a car's location, I want to update the corresponding `Car` object AND save the session to be able to redo and persist it to the server.

Incomplete diagram:

[image]

Code:

```
function Session(sessionId, objectsSave){
    this.objects = new Objects();

    if (objectsSave !== undefined)
        this.objects.restore(objectsSave);

Session.prototype.saveSession = function() {
    var save = this.objects.save();
    // persist to server and add to redoStack
}

function Objects() {
    this.objects = [];
}

Objects.prototype.restore = function(save){
    var objects = [];

    save.forEach(function(obj) {
        objects.push(Car.prototype.restore(obj));
    }); 

    this.objects = objects;
};

function Car(){
    this.markerOnMap = new Marker();
    this.markerOnMap.onDrag = this.setLocation;
    this.markerOnMap.onDragEnd = session.saveSession;  // here using the global variable, does not work when instantiating Session with a save object

Car.prototype.setLocation = function(e) {
    this.location = e.location;
}

var session = new Session();
```

The problem emerges (besides the "bad design" feeling) when I want to instantiate a `Session` e.g. with data from the server. In `Session` constructor I create a new `Objects` instance, and restore it with the save, which will create `Car` objects, which will try to reference a function of the global variable `session`. But `session` is not assigned yet, because this code was called from the constructor of `Session`.
I could have e.g. changed it to:

```
        this.markerOnMap.onDragEnd = function(){session.saveSession()};
```

or pass `this` from `Session` constructor all the way down to the constructor of `Car`.
I don't know what is worse, to have a global variable, all circular references, or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a design flaw in your construction process:  the `Car` requires the `Session` at its creation. This dependency then becomes an issue when the `Car` is deserialized during the resort of the `Session`.

The problem is due to the non respect of the [principle of single responsibility:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)  when you construct a `Car`, you should only create the object, and not insert it into some container.  This second step should be the responsibility of the function/object that instantiates the `Car` for a specific purpose.

In your case, I'd recommend to consider the [builder design pattern.](http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/builder-design-pattern).  This design separates the building of complex objects (here the Session) into building and assembling its parts. This requires that parts can be constructed independently.

Answer (score 0):

Your "bad design" feeling is justified. Communicating from one object to another through a global variable is definitely a code smell.

Providing a reference to the `Session` instance in the `Car` constructor does not sound that bad to me though. Alternatively `Car` could fire a `save` event rather than call `saveSession()` directly. A factory function would then be required to attach the event listener to `Session`, but `Car` would not have a direct dependency to `Session`.